# How to change assigned string with method

Tags: java, android, string, methods, replace

I am trying to write a program where when I use a button a "\" shows, then if I hit that same button a "X" shows, and finally if I hit that same button a third time "(X)" shows. Right now I have this method ......

```
public void display20closePlayer1(String close) {
    TextView playerOneTwentyClose = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.player_one_20_close);
    playerOneTwentyClose.setText(String.valueOf(close));
}
```

that finds the button and sets the text with this....

```
public void twentyCloseOutPlayer1(View v) {
    playerOneClose20 = playerOneClose20 + "\\";
    display20closePlayer1 (playerOneClose20);

}
```

I am storing the string in a public object in my main activity...

String playerOneClose20 = "";

When I run my code and press the button I get a "\" to show up, if I hit it again I get "\" and so on.

Can someone please help to explain a method that would replace the already called "\", with an "X" and then replace the "X" with "(X)" Thanks for the help!

Comment: https://www.javatpoint.com/java-string-replace ?

Comment: Did you try examining the current value of `playerOneClose20` within `twentyCloseOutPlayer1()` and then changing it according your specs?

Answer (score 0):

You’re close! The way I would do this is with a global `int` variable that denotes the stage you’re on (i.e `1 => “/“`, so on and so forth)

Then in your on button click listener get the text view and set it depending on the stage number.

**Remember to set and reset that `int` variable otherwise it will mess up your code**